# Tricky Poisson distribution question

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution, iid

Am new to probability and have been struggling to solve the following question.

> Assume $X_1, \ldots,X_4$ are IID with $X_i ∼ \text{Po}(λ)$. Let $Y = \frac{1}{4} (X_1 + \ldots + X_4)$.
>   Find $\text{Pr}(Y < 2)$ in terms of $\lambda$.

Can anyone explain the relevance of the random variables being IID? this seems to be putting me off.

Comment: I they were not iid they could all be equal, and equal to Y.

Comment: Imagine that instead of being IID, they were correlated. How would you answer the question differently?

Comment: To make @Glen_b's comment more specific, suppose "are IID" is dropped from the question. Let $Z_i\sim\text{Poisson}(\mu)$, $i=1,2,3,4$, and $Z\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda-\mu)$, with $0\lt\mu\lt\lambda$. When $(Z,Z_1,\ldots,Z_4)$ themselves are independent, you can (easily) check that $X_i=Z+Z_i\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ meet all the conditions of the question: they have identical Poisson distributions. However, $\Pr(Y\lt 2)$ appears to depend on $\mu$. Does it really, or do all the terms involving $\mu$ drop out in the calculation? You might find working through this to be instructive.

Answer (score 4):

"IID" stands for "independent, identically distributed", but the "identically distributed" part isn't really that important here (outside of convenience), at least in the sense that one could ask a similar question with different $\lambda$'s.

However, the independent part is critical, because it allows you to apply the result that a sum of independent Poisson random variables has a Poisson distribution, with mean equal to the sum of the component means. (When you don't have independence you don't generally have that a sum of Poissons is Poisson; an obvious exception is the case where all the $X_i$'s are equal.)

So rather than throwing you off, it makes the problem much easier than if the variables were dependent.

You can see that independence makes a difference by also considering the case where $X_1=X_2=X_3=X_4$.

[There's another neat trick that makes answering easier still. You're asked for $P(Y<2)$, but $Y=\overline{X}$, so $Y$ is not Poisson. The trick is to convert the event into an equivalent event that is easy to work with, given the abovementioned result.]

Comment: Logically, you also need to demonstrate that lack of independence actually can lead to a different answer.  (Although this is obvious to you, it might not be at all evident to someone new to the subject.)  In a comment to the question I have sketched one way to make this demonstration.

Comment: @whuber It's a good point for completeness' sake. The most obvious counterexample to a notion that "the sum of Poissons is Poisson" in general is one where all the $X_i$'s are equal.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of independent Poisson variables is itself Poisson distributed. In particular, if $X_1 \sim Poisson(\lambda_1)$ is independent of $X_2 \sim Poisson(\lambda_2)$, then the sum $X_1 + X_2 \sim Poisson(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$. Thus, the sample sum $S_n$ of $n$ independent and identical $Poisson(\lambda)$ variables:

$$S_n  = \sum _{i=1}^n X_i \quad \sim \quad Poisson(n \lambda) $$

with pmf, say, $f(s)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/poissonsamplesumpmf.png))</sub>

We can then find a general solution to $P(\frac{S}{n} < 2)$ not just for $n = 4$, but for any value of $n$, and for any desired probability (whether < 2 or a general parameter):

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/poissonprob.png))</sub>

where I am using the `Prob` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to compute, and `Gamma[a,z]` is the incomplete gamma function.

This is the same as the solution presented by David Stork, but more compact, and more general (solved for general $n$). For comparative purposes, when $\lambda = 1$ and $n=4$, the above probability is:

> 0.948866 ...

Answer (score 1):

```
Probability[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 < 8,
 {x1 \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]],
  x2 \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]],
  x3 \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]],
  x4 \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]}]
```

$
\frac{1}{315} e^{-4 \lambda } \left(1024 \lambda ^7+1792 \lambda ^6+2688 \lambda ^5+3360
   \lambda ^4+3360 \lambda ^3+2520 \lambda ^2+1260 \lambda +315\right)
$

Comment: The question asks for an explanation of the necessity of the iid assumption rather than for a particular numeric probability.

Comment: Just independence is needed - same approach (here or mine) would work fine without _identicality_.

Comment: @Wolfies It's not clear what you are saying by "needed", because neither your answer nor David's actually address the question of why the IID assumption is relevant. You have both computed distributional values assuming independence, but you have not explained why the independence assumption makes any material difference. To do that, at a minimum you would need to (1) exhibit variables that lack the IID property but otherwise satisfy all the conditions of the problem and (2) for which $\Pr(Y\lt 2)$ differs from the answer you have provided.

Comment: A simple example shows that the independence assumption is needed for my answer given above.  Assume that once $x_1$ is chosen, the remaining $x_i$ are set to be the same as $x_1$ (non-independence).  Then obviously the probability in question will not have the $\lambda^7 + ...$ dependence.

Comment: another way to put @whuber's point: the issue is not whether there exist dependent $X_i$ such that your formula **doesn't** hold (the answer is "obvious", as you say), but whether there exists a dependence structure for which it **does** hold!  (and I suspect one can cook up an example)

Comment: David, as I wrote in a comment to @Glen_b's answer, what is obvious to you might not be as obvious to others. Your answer is, at best, incomplete without that argument. Another disadvantage of this code-only response is that *Mathematica's* way of expressing the answer obscures how it was arrived at, thereby reducing its usefulness to anyone seeking insight--which is the whole point of working on elementary problems like this one.

Comment: @whuber The OP asks 2 questions:  (1) He states that he has `been struggling to solve the following question:  Find P(Y <2)`. Both David and I have provided a way of solving. /// (2) Second, the OP then asks: `Can anyone explain the relevance of the random variables being IID?` as it is 'putting him/her off'. The latter issue of independence (rather than identicality) is a very general question, in contrast to the specific sample mean of Poisson question component. To me, the rational course is to address specific questions where asked, and leave general questions to wiki or similar.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that the OP posed this question on the mathematica.SE site, and David answered this question on that site, which also helps explain the _Mathematica_ focus of these answers.

Comment: @wolfies Thank you for the explanation of the *Mathematica* code. On *our* site, we think most readers are able to recognize [tag:self-study] questions whether or not they are explicitly tagged as such and for them we ask respondents to follow [special procedures](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) that are nearly the opposite of your personal policy.  In particular, we ask people *not* to provide specific answers but instead to focus on giving useful guidance about how to obtain an answer. This is our way of pursuing the SE-wide goal of creating threads of lasting value.

Comment: @whuber That's the nice thing about software answers ... if it is actually a homework problem, the student still has to figure out how to do the mechanics themselves! :)

Comment: I do very much favour providing hints and tips for COMMENTS, but I don't think hints tend to provide 'threads of lasting value', because hints are inherently incomplete, and because they do not provide the final answer (for those seeking that), nor always even the series of steps required ... and one never knows how much knowledge the reader has. And if the knowledge already exists on a public forum like wiki and the question is homework and easy to google, there seems little value in expending effort, when a link to a fuller existing explanation might offer more, for less.

Comment: @Wolfies I see *negative* value in curating questions like "what is $\Pr(X_1+\cdots+X_4)\lt 2$." What do we do when somebody comes along next month and asks the same thing with the $4$ changed to a $3$? The $2$ to a $1$? Such questions must be put into some larger class, preferably associated with a canonical answer that explains how to solve them. This aim still leaves a lot to discuss--how finely resolved should that class be, how do we define it, etc.--but regardless, it suggests that mere numerical answers are with little merit in most cases and should be eschewed in favor of explanations.